# Ransack save search form value in advanced form search, save and edit these details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am developing an application for advanced search using ransack gem in ruby on rails. I am got stuck with the below problems

- How to save an form search value and save these details for later
  query
- Edit the saved query by generating an form by taking the existing
  query
- delete the query

Please help me find the solution for this.

Comment: I would try googling “search with ransack”. The first few results should be some excellent tutorials on getting started.

Comment: @ inveterateliterate I have implemented the advanced search, but problem is customer asking save these details and we can able to edit the search criteria. I am not getting any blog related to this.

Comment: I see. I recommend you share what you've done so far, what you've attempted to achieve your goals, and specifically where you're seeing issues.