# Ransack Advance Search Form Intact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, search-form

I'm using ransack advance search for one of my project.
I'm facing an issue wherein if I do a search and save the query I'm unable to rebuild the search form again with those queries. What exactly I'm looking for is that when I do a search I should be able to come back see the same form again with same values in it.

**layouts/_search.html.erb**

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: url, method: :post, class: search_form_class, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
    <%= render "layouts/condition_fields", f: c %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**layouts/_condition_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.attribute_fields do |a| %>
    <%= a.attribute_select %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.predicate_select %>
  <%= f.value_fields do |v| %>
    <%= v.text_field :value %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</div>
```

**people_controllers.rb**

```
  def index
    @search = Person.ransack(params[:q])
    @people = @search.result(distinct: true)
    @search.build_condition
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

**people/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/search', :locals => {:search => @search, :url => search_people_path, search_form_class: 'all_person'} %>
<div class="searchResult">
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/search_result', :locals => {:People => @people} %>
```

**layouts/_search_result.html.erb**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                </tr>
                <% @people.each do  |person|  %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= person.id %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= person.name %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= person.email %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>

    </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is now it appears now when i go the view.

[image: ransack advance search]

Looks like somebody ask similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646796/ransack-save-search-form-value-in-advanced-form-search-save-and-edit-these-deta)!

I exactly want the same thing.

1. How to save a form search value and save these details for later query
2. Edit the saved query by generating an form by taking the existing query

Answer (score 1):

For those reading this in the future: you can use the existence of the `params[:q]` values if any to apply default values to your search fields. It's a little hacky, but it is very simple and could suit your needs.

Here's something that's hacked together which might serve your needs:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :person_name_cont %>
    <% if params[:q] && params[:q][:person_name_cont]  %>
      <%= f.select :person_name_cont, Person.all.map(:name), {:include_blank => true, :selected => params[:q][:person_name_cont]} %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.select :person_name_cont, Person.all.map(:name), {:include_blank => true} %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to save this query as a `favorite` so you should create a `favorite` model

```
rails g model favorite url:string
```

The query you are performing is passed on the url as get request.

for example `http://localhost:3000/peoples?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=15`

this query is performing a `get` request on the url `http://localhost:3000/people` with parameters

```
people[:page] = 2
people[:sort] = newest
....
```

You can include a star icon on the page and [perform an ajax request as described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns) which will trigger the `favorites#create` action

```
def create
    Favorite.create(favorite_params)
end
```